# Selecting features using Adaboost

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, adaboost

How does Adaboost select best features from the sample data (or a unit feature vector)?

It would be nice if someone can explain if the above statement is true or not.

I've seen the term *features* and *classifiers* being used in place of each other in the documentation that's available of Adaboost (that's what I thought).

For example: [www.cs.nyu.edu/~eugenew/publications/viola-facedet04-talk.pdf](http://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eeugenew/publications/viola-facedet04-talk.pdf)

Please explain!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first of all in the presentation you mentioned they just used *a value of one feature is larger/smaller than some threshold* (i.e. decision tree of a depth 1) as a partial classifier, thus this feature-classifier ambiguity.

Going back to the question, there are numerous ways to get feature ranking from a boosting -- starting from counting how deep in boost structure the feature lies up to some permutation tests. In the work you quoted there is, in fact, no feature selection -- in training, they select the best feature/threshold pair, in prediction, they compute features "on demand" while the prediction goes through a boost to save computational time.

Comment: Can you give me some pointers to any existing implementation of adaboost or a paper that does "feature ranking" and training in the manner that you've mentioned?

Comment: @raul_w Check out R package `ada`'s `varplot` and `gbm`'s `summary` method of `gbm` objects. They have nice citations in the manuals.

Comment: I guess the confusion comes from many people describing Adaboost along with Haar features as classifiers. I found that there are very few intro slides on adaboost as an individual concept (or with some other classifier other than haar like decision trees).